# ProtectedLocalStorage - The type 'System.Int32[,]' is not supported

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to make a web app in Blazor which works as a golf scorecard. For a start I would like to simply save the active scorecard locally, using `ProtectedLocalStorage` (as described in [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server)). I can get it to work with a simple example, like a single integer, but when I try to save my scorecard, I get a number of errors, but this one is at the top of the stack:

> System.NotSupportedException: The type 'System.Int32[,]' is not
> supported.

It sounds like multidimensional arrays are not supported by `ProtectedLocalStorage.SetAsync()` but I cannot find anything about this in the documentation.

Does anyone know if this is intended or am I doing something wrong?

**Scorecard class**

```
public class Scorecard
{
    public Scorecard(int numberOfHoles, int maxStrokes, List<Player> players)
    {
        NumberOfHoles = numberOfHoles;
        MaxStrokes = maxStrokes;
        Players = players;
        Score = new int[Players.Count, NumberOfHoles];
    }

    public Guid Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public List<Player> Players { get; } = new List<Player>();

    public int[,] Score { get; private set; } = new int[0,0];

    public int MaxStrokes { get; set; } = 8;

    public int NumberOfHoles { get; } = 9;
}
```

**Player class**

```
public class Player
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Submit function**

```
private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
{
    var players = new List<Player>
    {
        new Player { Name = "Foo" },
        new Player { Name = "Bar" },
        new Player { Name = "Bas" }
    };

    var scorecard = new Scorecard(numberOfHoles: 9, maxStrokes: 8, players);
    await ProtectedLocalStorage.SetAsync("scorecard", scorecard);
}
```

Comment: Some hint is provided by the docs for `SetAsync` specifying that a "JSON-serializable value" must be used. Presumably multidimensional arrays have no default serialization format -- one could be devised, in theory, it just hasn't been done. Various workarounds suggest themselves -- `int[][]` and `Dictionary<int, int[]>` might be supported (disclaimer: not tested).